# Showing that if $d=\gcd(n,m)$ then the integers $\frac{n}{d}$ and $\frac{m}{d}$ are coprime

Tags: proof-explanation, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm, coprime

I'm having trouble understanding the indicated line from the solutions

Do a proof by contradiction by assuming there exists an $a > 1$ such that $a \mid \frac{n}{d}$ and $a \mid \frac{m}{d}$.

This implies (**I don't understan why!**) $ad\mid n$ and $ad\mid m$,

but $ad>d = \gcd(m,n)$, a contradiction.

Comment: Since $a|\frac{n}{d}$ and $a|\frac{m}{d}$, $ak=\frac{n}{d}$ and $al=\frac{m}{d}$ ($k,l$ are integers). This suggests $adk=n$ and $adl=m$ or $ad|n$ and $ad|m$. Thus $ad\neq d$ is the gcd which contradicts with the assumption that $d$ is the gcd.

Comment: If we have an integer $b$ such that $ab=\frac nd$ then $abd=n$.

Comment: No need to use contradiction. Let $a$ be a common divisor of $\frac{n}{d}$ and $\frac{m}{d}$. Then $ad$ is a common divisor of $n$ and $m$ and so divides $\gcd(n,m)=d$. Therefore, $a=1$.

Comment: @YourongZang, amazing, I understood the proof, but I wouldn't know how to start one on my own!

Comment: $\ a\mid b\,\Rightarrow\, ad\mid bd.\ $ OP is case $\,b = n/d\,$ so $\,bd = n\ \ $

Comment: @eriksan Next time you can try to start from the definitions and try to get something from the definitions.

Comment: $a\mid \frac nd$ means that $\frac nd = ak$ for some $k$ and $a\mid \frac md$ means that \frac nd = aj$ for some $j$.  So $n = d\cdot \frac nd= d(ak) = (ad)k$ and $m = d\cdot\frac md=d\cdot (aj) = (ad)j$.  So $ad|n$ and $ad|m$.